# Create a new dataframe by using other dataframe's column

Tags: r, dataframe, multiple-columns

I have a 496 dataframes of S&P 500 stocks. each dataframe have diffrent name and column name like these

```
         AAL.Open  AAL.High  AAL.Low AAL.Close   AAL.Volume
09-12-13    23.85   25.44   23.45      24.6        43197268
10-12-13    24.5    25.17   24.41      24.88       18660625

         AA.Open  AA.High   AA.Low  AA.Close    AA.Volume
09-12-13    22.5    24.25   20.13     21           6639
10-12-13    21.2    21.2    20.89     21           10963
```

Now I want to cteare a new Dataframe of 496 columns by taking a particular column of each dataframes like this

```
          AAL.High    AA.High   -----   ------
09-12-13    25.44     24.25
10-12-13    25.17      21.2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We place the datasets in a `list` and extract the column of interest.  Based on the OP's code, the column names are not exact.  SO, we could either use `grep`

```
do.call(cbind, lapply(lst, function(x) x[grep("High", names(x))]))
```

or the column position by numeric indexing

```
do.call(cbind, lapply(lst, function(x) x[2]))
```

NOTE: Assumed that the datasets are `data.frame`

#### data

```
lst <- list(d1, d2)
```

Or with `dput`

```
lst <- list(structure(list(AAL.Open = c(23.85, 24.5), AAL.High = c(25.44, 
 25.17), AAL.Low = c(23.45, 24.41), AAL.Close = c(24.6, 24.88), 
AAL.Volume = c(43197268L, 18660625L)), .Names = c("AAL.Open", 
 "AAL.High", "AAL.Low", "AAL.Close", "AAL.Volume"), class = "data.frame", 
 row.names = c("09-12-13", 
 "10-12-13")), structure(list(AA.Open = c(22.5, 21.2), AA.High = c(24.25, 
  21.2), AA.Low = c(20.13, 20.89), AA.Close = c(21L, 21L), 
 AA.Volume = c(6639L, 
 10963L)), .Names = c("AA.Open", "AA.High", "AA.Low", "AA.Close", 
 "AA.Volume"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("09-12-13", 
 "10-12-13")))
```

Comment: Error in lapply(lst, function(x) x[grep("High", names(x))]) : 
  object 'lst' not found

Comment: @SyedRiazMahmoodAli  The `lst` is a `list` object creating by keeping all the datasets in a `list`

Comment: Thank you. Can I create a new DF in global environment. not as a value

Comment: @SyedRiazMahmoodAli To avoid creating the list manually see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25510018/680068)

Comment: the first two formula only giving two row and two column result like this 
               AAL.High AA.High
09-12-13    25.44   24.25
10-12-13    25.17   21.20

Comment: @SyedRiazMahmoodAli  You only showed two dataset each with 2 rows.  I am just copy/pasting your example to do this.  For your original dataset, get all the dataset in list and then apply the code.  Also, I am assuming that you have a `data.frame`.  If it is matrix, then use `x[, 2]`

Comment: when I do this 2nd<-list('AAPL', 'ABT', 'ABBV', 'ACN',.............................) and  ddf8<-do.call(cbind, lapply(2nd, function(x) x[grep("High", names(x))]))
Error: unexpected symbol in "ddf8<-do.call(cbind, lapply(2nd"

Comment: @SyedRiazMahmoodAli  Is that name of the object?  If it is the object name then `lst <- list(AAPL, ABT, ABBV, ...)` without quotes

Comment: when I put it without quotes it shows : 3rd <-list(ABT, ABBV, ACN, ACE, ADBE, ADT, AAP, AES)
Error: unexpected symbol in "3rd"

Comment: @SyedRiazMahmoodAli  I think you are not giving full information.  What is `ABT`, `ABBV` etc.  Is it like `ABT <- data.frame(col1 = .., col2 = ...)`

Comment: ABT, ABBV, ACN ect are the  496 symbols of all s&p 500 indexed companies stock data which I have downloaded by r.  Now the company symbols represents 496 Dataframes contain 5 columns each which I mentioned in the main question. I want to create a new dataframe or matrix of containing 496 coumn (2nd column)

Comment: @SyedRiazMahmoodAli Can  u show how u r getting the dataset

Comment: @SyedRiazMahmoodAli  If you want to download multple elements in a list, take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37290727/using-lapply-to-find-individual-mean-across-multiple-dataframes-error-incorrec) and then use the code above

Comment: require(quantmod),  quantmod_list <- c('AAPL', 'ABT', 'ABBV', 'ACN', 'ACE',...............)    for(company in quantmod_list){
  try(getSymbols(company, auto.assign = TRUE, src="google"))
  print(company)
}

Comment: @SyedRiazMahmoodAli  TRy to put it in a `list` using `lst <-  lapply(symbols, function(sym) {getSymbols(sym, from=StartDate, auto.assign=FALSE)})`  specify the `StartDate` if you have one.  I can't execute this command as it is blocked in my work location

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153098/discussion-between-syed-riaz-mahmood-ali-and-akrun).

Comment: @SyedRiazMahmoodAli  Can you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43573018/for-loops-for-functions-containing-multiple-arguments-r/43573856)  This one should work as I was able to do that at that time

Comment: @akrun It is now working. I am not sure why it was not working initially. Thank you so much for your support.